# Collection View Controller Doesn't show content

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I embedded a collection view controller inside a navigation controller the set a view controllers segue to that navigation controller from a tabBar controller but when my collection view controller loads it doesn't display anything! Here is my code

```
class HomeVC: UICollectionViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 220)
}


override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! HeaderView

    header.fullnameLbl.text = (PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "name") as? String)?.capitalized
    header.webTxt.text = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "web") as? String
    header.webTxt.sizeToFit()
    header.bioLbl.text = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "bio") as? String
    header.bioLbl.sizeToFit()
    header.button.setTitle("Edit Profile", for: .normal)

    let avaQuery = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "ava") as! PFFile

    avaQuery.getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
        if let err = error{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let imageData = data{
            header.avaImg.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    }

    return header
}




}
```

[image: and this is what my simulator looks like]

[image: I want it to look like this]

Anybody know why this is happening? I seem to always run into this issue when using collection view controllers.

Comment: Well, for starters you are returning 0 in `numberOfSections:`. You're telling the collection view that there are 0 sections, and therefore 0 items. Change that to 1 and see what happens then.

Comment: haha didn't even notice that. That fixed it, thank you!